# Angular Material slider - show min and max labels

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material slider and I would like to display at both ends of the slider labels representing the min and max value set for the slider. Optionally I would like to show a scale with points and relative labels showing which value is related to which point.
This is a feature present in other sliders provided by javascript libraries, but I do not find a similar capability in the Angular Material slider APIs. I am wondering if a similar behavior can be obtained also with the slider provided by Angular Material.

Comment: Please include your current code.

Comment: There is no specific code I have written. I am just using the standard APIs offered by angular material slider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is clearly provided on the [documentation page for Angular Material's slider component](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview).

```
<md-slider
    min="1" max="5" // min & max values
    step="0.5" // step at which the slider control moves, if not given it will move smoothly
    tickInterval="1" // interval at which a tick is shown on the slider, if not given there will be none
    thumbLabel // show the selected value when the user moves the slider
    value="1" // initial value
></md-slider>
```

You cannot display the min & max values using the component's controls, since Material Design guidelines do not allow for it. But it's easy enough to just add them yourself in the template. For example, something like:

```
<span class="text-small">1</span><md-slider></md-slider><span class="text-small">5</span>
```